# How to handle shutdown \ logoff in console application?

Tags: winapi

I'm writting a console application in C++.

I use SetConsoleCtrlHandler to trap any application close (CTRL+C, close console, windows shutdown or logoff).

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

BOOL CtrlHandler( DWORD fdwCtrlType ) 
{   
  switch( fdwCtrlType ) 
  { 
    // Handle the CTRL-C signal. 
    case CTRL_C_EVENT: 
      printf( "Ctrl-C event\n\n" );
      Beep( 750, 300 );
      return( TRUE );

    // CTRL-CLOSE: confirm that the user wants to exit. 
    case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT: 
      Beep( 600, 200 ); 
      printf( "Ctrl-Close event\n\n" );
      return( TRUE ); 

    // Pass other signals to the next handler. 
    case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT: 
      Beep( 900, 200 ); 
      printf( "Ctrl-Break event\n\n" );
      return FALSE; 

    case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT: 
      Beep( 1000, 200 ); 
      printf( "Ctrl-Logoff event\n\n" );
      return FALSE; 

    case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT: 
      Beep( 750, 500 ); 
      printf( "Ctrl-Shutdown event\n\n" );
      return FALSE; 

    default: 
      return FALSE; 
  } 
} 

int main( void ) 
{       
  //MessageBoxA(0, "test", "test", 0); // ****************

  if( SetConsoleCtrlHandler( (PHANDLER_ROUTINE) CtrlHandler, TRUE ) ) 
  { 
    printf( "\nThe Control Handler is installed.\n" ); 
    printf( "\n -- Now try pressing Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break, or" ); 
    printf( "\n    try logging off or closing the console...\n" ); 
    printf( "\n(...waiting in a loop for events...)\n\n" ); 

    while( 1 ){ } 
  } 
  else 
  {
    printf( "\nERROR: Could not set control handler"); 
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is msdn example and it works fine, until I uncomment marked line. When I do it, my application handles CTRL+C, CTRL+Break and console close, but on shutdown or logoff it simply close without any reaction.

Windows 7, MSVC 10 Express Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you show a dialog from a console app, a message loop is created for that thread.

And once you've got a message loop, you have to handle [WM_ENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [related](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376881%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages.

Comment: This happens not only after MessageBoxA, but also OemToCharBuffA or some calls in boost::asio

Comment: I create invisible window in addition thread and handle WM_ENDSESSION in it messageproc